# Can certain families of probability distributions be considered as groups?

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

*Disclaimer: It is very possible that the notation I will be using is not formally correct. I am not a mathematician, and I'm just trying to write down this idea in a reasonable way. I wasn't able to find literature addressing this topic*

As an example, take the family of univariate normal distributions with the sum operation. Let see if it satisfies the four defining properties of a group:

**Closure**: Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^{2})$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\,\sigma_2^{2})$, $Z = X+Y$ is also normally distributed, with $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1+\mu_2,\,\sigma_1^{2}+\sigma_2^{2})$

**Associativity**: It is clear that $(X + Y) + Z = X + (Y + Z)$ in distribution, with $X, Y, Z$ each independently and normally distributed with given means and variances.

**Identity element**: The distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\,0)$ is the identity element, because any $I \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,0)$ satisfies the property that $Y = X + I = I + X$ is distributed as $X$, with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^{2})$.

**Inverse element**: In this case for any $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^{2})$, there exists $-X$ such that $X-X = -X+X = I$, with $I \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,0)$.

The four properties seem to be satisfied, therefore couldn't we say that the family of univariate normal distributions with the sum operation constitutes a group? And the same with other several families of distributions and different operations such as sum, product, ratio, etc.

**Edit**: As pointed out below, I should have added that $X$ and $Y$ have to be independent in the first point, otherwise the expression for the variance of the addition is not correct.

Comment: How would you get a negative variance for your inverse?

Comment: I think the inverse element is problematic. It doesn't suffice to take an arbitrary random variable with the same distribution as $-X$, it has to be $-X$ itself. So the distributions don't form a group, but one could reasonably say that the random variables with these distributions do form a group, for the reasons you gave.

Comment: I was realizing now about this problem. It does seem pathological in that sense. I think I didn't nail down the distinction between "a random variable following a certain distribution family" and "that distribution family".

Comment: By the way, your claim that the variance of $X+Y$ is $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ holds if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but not necessarily if they are not. Also, you need to assume somewhere that the family of random variables are jointly distributed.

Comment: *Any* set can be given a group structure (if you allow the Axiom of Choice). Of course, it may not be the particular group structure you have in mind, so it may not be compatible with the operations you define.

Comment: @Bungo actually I think that I could have formalized the question better by asking if the density function of a particular family of distribution forms a group under, for example, convolution (in the case of addition of independent random variables).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\,\sigma_2^2)$, $Z = X+Y$ is also normally distributed, with $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1+\mu_2,\,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$

You neglected **independence.**

As it stands, this is not true. It is true if $X,Y$ are independent. Thus your group operation corresponds to addition of **independent** random variables. There is no inverse element because there is no probability distribution for which, if $Y$ has that distribution and $X$ is as above and $X,Y$ are independent, then $X+Y \sim \mathcal N(0,0).$ In particular, $X$ and $-X$ are not independent. So this is a semigroup but not a group.

Variances are always nonnegative, and the variance of the sum of two **independent** random variables is at least as big as either of their variances, so you won't get back to $0.$

Comment: The variance formula isn't right if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, but $X+Y$ is still normally distributed, so closure is OK. The identity is OK if we admit the degenerate zero-mean, zero-variance distribution. Inverses are problematic, however.

Comment: @Bungo : But how is the operation on probability distributions defined if independence is not assumed? You have two normal distributions; What is their "sum"?

Comment: Ah right, good point. The OP would find it more fruitful to look at random variables rather than their distributions.

Comment: @Bungo : And in that case it's trivial.

Comment: Thank you for answer and comments. I indeed forgot to mention explicitly that the random variables have to be independent (I mentioned in the second point, but didn't mention it overall). And I just learned about the concept of semigroup. Does a semigroup that have identity element but not inverse element receive a special name?
And another question, this one a bit more "philosophical". Why isn't it assumed by default that when you are talking about two random variables sampled from a particular family of univariate distributions, they are independent? Why would they be correlated?

Comment: The special name is "monoid".

Comment: @verret I was digging a bit more and I think the structures I'm considering are semimodules, because there are commutative monoids and they also support scalar multiplication. This was helpful to learn a lot of new concepts about algebraic structures.

Comment: @J.R.C. Your wrote: "Why isn't it assumed by default that when you are talking about two random variables sampled from a particular family of univariate distributions, they are independent? Why would they be correlated?" If the context is ONLY mathematics, then that should be there because in some cases random variables are not independent. But if the context is application of mathematics to something else, then this question develops subtleties in some cases.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I understand the reasons for which you say this. It's just that in my mind, if someone mentions "two random variables", they are disconnected, therefore independent, because nothing has been said that suggests the opposite, no structure has been given. If two random variables are not independent, **then** it is when I imagine two nodes of a probabilistic graphical model that are somehow connected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ we can think of the measurable functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ as a group under addition.

But you are aiming on a group of distributions, right?

These are in fact probability measures on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$.

If you want probability distributions (of a certain kind) to be a group then you are forced to define multiplication $\mathsf{P}\cdot \mathsf{Q}$ (or $\mathsf{P}+ \mathsf{Q}$ if you want an abelian group)  where $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{Q}$ are probability distributions of that kind.

It seems you seek your hail in taking random variables $X,Y$ defined on the same probability space such that $\mathsf{P}=P_X$ and $\mathsf{Q}=Q_Y$ and then to state that $\mathsf{P}\cdot \mathsf{Q}=P_X\cdot P_Y=P_{X+Y}$.

But like that the multiplication $\cdot$ is certainly not well-defined.

If e.g. $\mathsf P=\mathsf Q$ and denotes a distribution symmetric wrt $0$ then can take $Y=X$ and also $Y=-X$, leading to different results.